# How to replace style with javascript that has already been set?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm implementing menu that is selected by the help of javascript. In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/u66PY/1/).
Blocks are selected by the help of changing the style in innerHTML of div here.

**But how to replace the style that has already been set?**

Here my problem is I cannot select **block 1**.

full html code:

```
<style>
div {width:10px;height:10px;margin:10px;
    background:#ccc;cursor:pointer;padding:10px;
}
</style>
<div id="makeThatEnable" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="one" onclick="makeThisEnable(this.id)" style="border:1px solid #00f">1</div>
<div id="two" onclick="makeThisEnable(this.id)">2</div>
<div id="three" onclick="makeThisEnable(this.id)">3</div>
<div id="four" onclick="makeThisEnable(this.id)">4</div>
<div id="five" onclick="makeThisEnable(this.id)">5</div>
<br>
Click on box to select it.

<script>
function makeThisEnable(id) {
    document.getElementById('makeThatEnable').innerHTML="<style> #"+id+" {border:1px solid #f00}</style>";   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have a better approach.*
Uniquely identify a style element like this

```
<style id="innerStyle">
</style>
```

Then update your function like this

```
function makeThisEnable(id) {
    document.getElementById('innerStyle').innerHTML="div#"+id+" {border:1px solid #f00}";   
}
```

Instead of using **`!important`** to force the style, simple increase the **specificity** of the declaration like I am doing.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aryEz/)

Comment: @vusan, Specially using this way. It does not use a extra container `div` which is present in DOM but does not show itself. Moreover, the use of `!important` should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

add `!important` at the end of CSS like -->

`document.getElementById('makeThatEnable').innerHTML="<style> #"+id+" {border:1px solid #f00 !important;}</style>";`

Comment: @vusan, There are better ways, than using `!important`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute method

```
document.getElementById('makeThatEnable').setAttribute('css', 'your prefered style');
```

Comment: I do not want to set style into that id. And please tell me that is css is an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes (boxed, unboxed). When clicked set all items to unboxed first then set the clicked item to boxed.

```
<style>
.boxed 
    {border:1px solid #f00}
.unboxed
    {border:0px solid #f00}
</style>

<script>
function makeThisEnable(id) {
    var ids = new Array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).setAttribute("class", "unboxed");       
    }
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "boxed");     
}
</script>
```